# Revit Python Pick Object / Select Object

Tags: python, api, revit, revitpythonshell

I'm fairly new to coding, so this might be obvious.

Why do I get an error "name 'ObjectType' not defined" when I run this code:

```
picked = uidoc.Selection.PickObject(ObjectType.Element)
```

I'm using revit python shell (IronPython)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should import `ObjectType` into the current scope:

```
>>> from Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection import ObjectType
>>> picked = uidoc.Selection.PickObject(ObjectType.Element)
```

I have just tried this out in the RevitPythonShell and have noticed, that it doesn't work, because the shell is still in the foreground. So, this technique will work for scripts that you add to the Ribbon, but not directly from the shell... I'm not quite sure how to fix this yet. Sorry.

**EDIT:** Use a function like this one to do the trick:

```
def pickobject():
    from Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection import ObjectType
    __window__.Hide()
    picked = uidoc.Selection.PickObject(ObjectType.Element)
    __window__.Show()
    __window__.Topmost = True
    return picked
```

You can run this by pasting it into the editor pane at the bottom and hitting F5 or adding it to your Init-Script or whatever. And then just call `pickobject()` when you need to pick an Element.

Comment: Daren,  Thank you!!

I'm just starting to figure out programming and using revit's SDK.  I've been checking out your site and jeremy tammik's, but It's still coming along slowly.

Comment: @dciolino, hey you're welcome! Just hang in there, soon everything will start to make sense ;-) I get emails from StackOverflow for questions tagged revit and revitapi, so feel free to ask!

Answer (score 1):

It's because `ObjectType` is not defined anywhere in that statement's scope:

```
>>> ObjectType
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ObjectType' is not defined
>>> ObjectType = 12
>>> ObjectType
12
```

Maybe you forgot an import statement?