# Can't prompt the user to pick a room with Revit Python Shell

Tags: revit-api, revit, revitpythonshell

Using the Revit Python Shell, I'm trying to prompt the user to pick a room.
I've been reading and implementing the method described here [Revit Python Pick Object / Select Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296317/revit-python-pick-object-select-object) .
It works fine, but using that I can only select walls, floors, doors, etc. .. but not rooms. Why is that ?

Outside the shell, I can perfectly well select the rooms.

Other tutorials seem to indicate that it shouldn't be a problem, see http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?id=16509155&siteID=123112 for instance.

Thanks a lot for any help !

Arnaud.

PS: I can select the room tag, but it seems to be a dead end to access the room from there (?)

Comment: Apparently by hitting tab many times, the room becomes suddenly pickable... but that's not very clean :s Maybe that's why they use a filter in the second link I provide above...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your own comment is the perfect answer. In many situations, several superimposed objects might be selected by one single click. You can use the tab key to cycle through them. Specifying a selection filter for the specific type of object you are interested in or even specific detailed properties on it enable you to avoid the requirement for tabbing through the other unwanted objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback Jeremy, I'm currently spending 8 hours a day reading your blog ;)

Comment: wow. i hope you can cram in more time coding than reading   :-)  thank you for the appreciation!